# Network syslog with port number

Tags: networking, nat, port, syslog

I am collecting syslog from VoIP phones over the network and it is usual  having several phones behind same NAT device.

I need to collect syslog files to different files or be able to differ lines from different devices in single file.

Only difference between syslog received - SRC port number. Is there any syslog server exists, that able to use port number in log file name or in log records template?

Comment: Behind NAT? Hopefully you're encrypting the traffic over the internet. Which syslog server do you use? What OS is it on? What model VoIP phones are involved?

Comment: Currently we run latest Ubuntu with rsyslog, we use Yealink voip phones.